# It's/they're a pair of shoes

Tags: pronouns, subject-verb-agreement, complements

It might seem a trivial question but it occured to me whlie I was writing for an assignment.

I know if I put *a pair of* in subject place, I should use a singular verb e.g. *A pair of shoes is there*. Does it work the other way around too?

What subject suits this sentence, a singular or plural one:

> .... is/are a pair of shoes.

This is confusing for me because on the one hand when you point at some shoes actually you're showing something that is originally a plural noun so it must be addressed as plural. On the other hand we want to use *a pair of* which is singular. So which is correct?

> It's a pair of shoes.
>
> They're a pair of shoes.

Comment: Wow! I'm getting different answers. Well I'm not really in place to say which is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your examples, both are correct, but it depends on what you are referring to

> It is a pair of shoes.
>   It is a pair of two halves.
>
> *It is a pair*

in these examples one is describing the "pair"edness of the objects.

> They are a pair of shoes.
>   Those are a nice pair of melons.
>
> *two somethings are a pair*

in these examples one is describing the objects as a "pair".

Comment: Thank you Peter. Is this applicable to plural nouns that always are plural like jeans? I mean here again can we use both _it's/they're a pair of jeans_?

Answer (score 1):

Many group nouns can take either take a singular or plural conjugation depending on the dialect of the speaker. These include things like *band*, *group*, and *pair*. In general, BE prefers a plural form for these nouns and AmE a singular form.

EDIT: Here's some data from the GloWbE corpus for usage frequencies.

"Pair are":

[image: Pair are]

"Pair is":

[image: Pair is]

Comment: So both sentences are right? _It's/They're a pair of shoes_.

Comment: Yes, essentially. I'd suggest you pick the one that corresponds to the variety of English you're learning, like AmE or BE, and stick to using it.

Comment: What about AusE and NZE?

Comment: @3kstc AusE and NZE "pair is" FREQ / SIZE (M) / PER MIL -  AUS 81 / 148.2 / 0.55 | NZ 56 / 81.4 / 0.69. "Pair are" : AUS 53 / 148.2 / 0.36 | NZ 48 / 81.4 / 0.59. Queries: ["pair is"](http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=49100304), ["pair are"](http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=49100301) - select Frequency to see results.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pair of shoes.

They are shoes.

Grammatically a pair is singular.